# Is this tag de[composable]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

A [recent meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427001) drew my attention to the [composable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composable) tag. There are 171 questions, but no usage guidance whatsoever.

I think this is a straightforward candidate for burnination, per the usual criteria:

1. *Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?*

   No. In a generic computer science sense, "composable" means something like "permitted to be a component of something that has components, such as a(n instance of a) product type or record type". But that's the default expectation for anything that could be called an object.

   It seems like this tag is being applied to questions about frameworks that use some kind of decorator named "composable"; but there are multiple such frameworks apparently for different languages (at least JavaScript and Kotlin, it appears). It's not evident to me that these tools do fundamentally the same thing in each such language, or how to describe that thing.
2. *Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?*

   No; it doesn't describe a concept clearly enough in the first place to judge the topicality of that concept.
3. *Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?*

   Certainly not. It's not clear what the frameworks mentioned above *do* without knowing that particular framework; but then one is an expert in the framework, not in things that are "composable".
4. *Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?*

   No (already explained).

This tag also causes clear potential harm to the site: several of these questions end up with a full set of five tags but *no programming language tag*, and it seems likely to attract mis-tagged questions that are about the general computer-science technique of composition and how to apply it - i.e., the [composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composition) tag.

Answer (score 9):

This tag should not be burninated because it does not fit the criteria for burnination. It does seem like a prime candidate for retagging and renaming, however. My suggestion would be to retag the Vue questions with [vue-composition-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-composition-api) and add [vue-composables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-composables) as a synonym (assuming they're the same concept). The remaining questions can then be merged into [android-jetpack-compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-jetpack-compose) which seems to have more questions (and then remove the synonym).

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

After looking through the tag (see [tag search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/composable+-vuejs3+-android+-android-jetpack-compose+-vue.js)), it refers to one of two things: [Vue Composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html) or [Jetpack Compose's `@Composable`](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial). There were 1 or two questions beyond this which I retagged.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Yes, `@Composable` is an annotation from the UI toolkit Jetpack Compose for Android developers and Vue Composables are a type of function in that respective framework.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Probably not for Jetpack Compose questions, in the same way that it's unnecessary to tag something [vs-unit-testing-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vs-unit-testing-framework)[testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/testing): the framework is all about the concept.

For Vue, I think so. See [vue-composition-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vue-composition-api) which I think refers to the same concept.

Comment: Okay, actually I'm confused now. What more does burnination actually involve besides a systematic retagging and renaming?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel In general "burninate" means "delete". But in this case the tag *shouldn't* be deleted because it provides additional context to help sort through Vue questions. See the meta tags [meta-tag:retag-request] and [meta-tag:tag-disambiguation]. In the past I've been burned (heh) by people not doing the research into the concept that the tag actually represents to the people who use the technology and just assuming it should be merged into another tag or removed completely, which is hard to undo.

Comment: I am a member of the Jetpack Compose team and I (personally, not as a representative of the team) endorse the view in this answer that the tag adds no info to Jetpack Compose questions as currently used (though there are quite a few questions about it tagged [composable] and _not_ [android-jetpack-compose], which needs to be fixed).  It is possible that a [composable-functions] tag could be useful, for asking about the behavior of such functions, but it's currently being used to include any use of `@Composable` UI components, making it so broad as to include nearly any Compose question.

Comment: @RyanM Ah, it's about *function* composition then?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Not really, at least in the traditional sense. [Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) or [Compose From First Principles](https://intelligiblebabble.com/compose-from-first-principles/) (currently having some SSL cert issues) are decent explanations of what it is.  It's in many ways the basic building block of a Compose app, and many such functions are nouns rather than verbs, so it's not really function composition in the traditional sense (though it supports it).

Comment: Yeah, "composition" is a distinct concept within the discipline of functional programming at large, but it appears the vast majority of uses of the tag here are related to either vue or jetpack, regardless whether the functional sense plays a role in the framework's implementation.

That said, I think #2 could be a "maybe" in very specific contexts, but enforcing a `functional-composition` tag would take care of that.